# How to make a bind datetimepicker

Tags: wpf, winforms, datetimepicker

I am using wpf framework 3.5 for this I had to use winworms -> datetimepicker.
I need to do Binding on the Text

```
<wfi:WindowsFormsHost >
     <wf:DateTimePicker Format="Short" Text="{Binding date, Converter={StaticResource conkey}}" x:Name="p_datePicker" />
</wfi:WindowsFormsHost>
```

EDIT:
Answer: The need to use WPF toolKit DatePicker and do not forget to connect the reffrenses

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Arcturus explained, you can't use bindings on Windows Forms controls. Why don't you use the [WPF Toolkit](http://wpf.codeplex.com/releases/view/40535) `DatePicker` instead ? It has a `SelectedDate` property that you can bind

Comment: DatePicker works fine in 3.5, I use it in the application I develop at work.

Comment: I'm dumb = (Thank you merely had to include the refferns

Answer (score 0):

You can't..

WinForms controls do not have any DependencyProperties so Bindings are out!

Get and set it by hand in the code behind!

Comment: I see you are using a DataGrid. Try to find a WPF DatePicker. WPF 4.0 has one out of the box, and you can find some DatePickers on various toolkits: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/llobo/archive/2009/11/23/new-wpf-features-datepicker-calendar-vsm-datagrid.aspx